# If $f(x,y,z,a,b)=0$, then how come $f_x+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} f_z=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My partial differential equations textbook by Tyn Myint-Yu says the following:

> We consider a system of geometrical surfaces described by the equation $f(x,y,z,a,b)=0$, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary parameters. We differentiate this with respect to $x$ and $y$ to get $f_x+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} f_z=0$ and $f_y+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} f_z=0$.

I don't understand how. I know that $f_x=f_y=f_z=0$. Is this just another redundant way of doing $0+(\text{something}\times 0)=0$?

Also,

> The two parameters $a$ and $b$ can be eliminated to form an equation of the form $F(x,y,z,\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})$.

What if $f=e^{ax}+ax^2$? How do you eliminate $a$ then?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions $u$ and $f$ are such that $f(x,y,u(x,y))=0$ for every $(x,y)$, then, considering $g(x,y)=f(x,y,u(x,y))$, one has $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0,$$ that is, by the chain rule,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0,
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0.
$$

> I know that $f_x=f_y=f_z=0$.

Not necessarily true. Try to find counterexamples.

Comment: @Did- Thanks! As for my second question?

Comment: I fail to understand it. What is the surface defined in your example, already?

Comment: @Did- No it is not.

Comment: "It is not" what? Your setting is the study of a surface. What is the surface in the example you added afterwards and modified later on and are asking about?

Comment: The book specifies no particular surface. It says $a$ and $b$ can be eliminated for every such surface. I'm asking for a proof of this assertion. The example that I have given (and later modified), come to think about it, is misleading as it might not be a surface at all. So perhaps my question should have been "can you prove that $a$ and $b$ can always be eliminated, given that $f(x,y,z,a,b)$ is a surface?"

Comment: The book probably says that a and b can be eliminated for every *generical* surface, not for every surface. The idea is probably that three equations in $(x,y,z,a,b)$ can often be combined to get one equation in $(x,y,z)$ only. (Yes your example is misleading, but in your example $f=0$ is either empty or a plane, hence a surface.)

Answer (score 0):

The equation $f(x,y,z,a,b)=0$ defines an implicit function $z(x,\ y),$ so, by applying the chain rule we have
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\left({f(x,y,z(x,\ y),a,b)}\right) =0 $$ 
or
$$\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}+\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}\cdot\dfrac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}=0.$$